# Get data from Flask on Submit to Browser as Input for Bootstrap Modal

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a button that submits a user input form:

```
<input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="View Code" id="retrieve">
```

After the submit I have Flask functions that process the data and returns it:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/home")
def filters():
  if request.method == "POST":

      # Get all input params
      <assigning variables based on request.form[key]>

      # button functionality
      submit_button = request.form["submit_button"]
      if submit_button == "View Data":
          df = <function to get data as pd.DataFrame based on request.form[keys]>
      
          return render_template(
              "view.html", 
              column_names=df.columns.values,
              # data=df.to_html()
              row_data=list(df.values.tolist()),
              zip=zip,
          )

      elif submit_button == "View Code":
          sql_code = <function to process request>
          return jsonify({'sql_code': sql_code})

  return render_template(
          "home.html",
          show_titles=show_titles,
          station_names=station_names,
      )
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is the jQuery AJAX call to get this data back to client. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$("#retrieve").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var sql_code = $("#sql_code").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "/", //home page route name
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({sql_code: sql_code}),
    success: function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      alert('something went wrong' + xhr);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Does this work? `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: Did you update your flask to process json data?

Comment: Are there any errors at all in the browser's development console?  In the browser's development tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain what you expect?  What is the server's response?  At a glance, where do you ever define the `data` variable that you're passing to `JSON.stringify` when making the request?

Comment: @Musa updated but still has error (below)
@David after defining ```data``` variable and processing json in flask. I am getting ```500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)``` on console

Comment: You should post all the route code so we can see what's happening

Comment: @Musa I posted but I don't think it's a route code issue. I can print out ```sql_code``` without any issues. It's getting that back to client I'm having trouble with. Perhaps I'm overlooking something...

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale: Then there's an error happening on the server.  If the response body doesn't contain any useful information about that error then check any server logs, debug the server-side code, etc.  You need to find out what the error is.

Comment: @David I'm having trouble understanding how it's a server-side error if server side can print out the jsonifed object without any issues.

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale: Because HTTP 500 is, as the message states, an "internal server error".  So there's an error happening on the server.  Can you clarify what you mean by *"server side can print out the jsonifed object without any issues"*?  So, when you're inspecting the AJAX response in the debugging tools, the response body still contains the expected output?

Comment: @David AJAX response doesn't show anything. I'm guessing the problem is that the submit button sends a POST. I am trying to trigger an AJAX request to GET the posted data after the post. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale: If the response is empty (which I'd expect from a 500 response), what do you mean by *"server side can print out the jsonifed object without any issues"*?  Where is it "printing" this information if not in the response?  Are you referring to some logged output somewhere?  Also, what is this GET operation you're referring to?  Isn't the question about the failing AJAX POST operation?  It's really not clear what you're trying to describe here.

Comment: @David sorry for the confusion. When I say "server side can print out the jsonfieid object without any issues", what I mean is that when I run ```print(jsonify({'sql_code': sql_code})``` I get the response ```<Response 1668 bytes [200 OK]>``` on the server Flask side indicating there is no issue with the input submit POST and post-processing. What I'm struggling to figure out is how to get the processed data back to the client. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale: Being able to successfully perform one operation server-side is not an indication that all operations everywhere on the server are guaranteed to be successful.  The bottom line is that your server is reporting that there is an error when processing that AJAX POST request.  You need to find out what that error is in order to correct it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244885/discussion-between-whimsicalwhale-and-david).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to send data back from Flask to the browser (client) for Modals via single input button (along with other buttons), here is my solution:

**routes.py:**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if len(request.form) > 0: # if submitting POST via input
        submit_button = request.form[<key>]
        ... 
    elif len(request.form) == 0: # if submitting POST via AJAX
        submit_button = request.json[<key>]
        ...
    
    if submit_button == "<value tag of HTML button>":
       obj = <APPLY FUNCTIONS>
       return jsonify(obj)
```

**home.html:**

```
<script>
$( function() {
    function convertFormToJSON(form) {
        const array = $(form).serializeArray(); // Encodes the set of form elements as an array of names and values.
        const json = {};
        $.each(array, function () {
            json[this.name] = this.value || "";
        });
        return json;
        }
    
    // open Modal to view code after submit
    $("#retrieve").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form_inputs = $("#input_form"); //takes input values
        var form_json = convertFormToJSON(form_inputs)
        form_json.submit_button = $("#retrieve").val() //append button type to json

        $.ajax({
            url: "/", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(form_json),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
                $('.modal-body').text(data);
                $('#openModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                alert('something broke'+xhr)
            }
        })
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server is not expecting JSON data(it's expecting form-data) so don't send JSON data, send form data.

```
$("#retrieve").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var sql_code = $("#sql_code").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "/", //home page route name
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {sql_code: sql_code, [this.name]: this.value},// the second value is for the button that was pressed
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      alert('something went wrong' + xhr);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: I am not trying to send form data. The submit button in my HTML already sends the form inputs. I am trying to get data back as JSON **after** the submit POST is processed (in Flask).

Comment: Then why is your server code reading form data?

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale: For example, in your server-side code you are reading this value: `request.form["submit_button"]`  But in your client-side code you are (1) only posting a value called `sql_code` (so no value called `submit_button`) and (2) JSON-stringifying the whole thing instead of just posting it as direct form values.  Based on this and your responses so far, it honestly sounds like you're confused on what you're even trying to do, let alone why it isn't working.

Comment: @Musa @David (1) client-side accepts inputs and sends to server-side which is read as ```request.form['submit_button']```. (2) depending on the button which is pressed (an input value attribute), server-side runs functions one of which I'm trying to (3) push back to client-side as JSON string into a Modal. I don't think this should be a difficult task but I'm not that familiar with AJAX so struggling with part 3. Perhaps using AJAX isn't even required?

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale: *"accepts inputs and sends to server-side [...] depending on the button which is pressed (an input value attribute)"* - None of that is true in the code you're showing us.  This is the data you're sending to the server: `data: JSON.stringify({sql_code: sql_code})`  That, **and only that**, is the information being sent to the server.  *"Perhaps using AJAX isn't even required?"* - Since you seem to be **very** confused on what you're doing with this AJAX request/response, perhaps it is indeed a good idea to remove it entirely and go back to form posts.

Comment: @David @Musa I figured it out, you guys were right with server-side being an issue. Basically my cursory understanding of AJAX was wrong, I needed to first POST all values from input forms using AJAX which actually on the server-side returned a ```request.json``` object. I had to code around it to work well with non-AJAX posts ```if len(request.form) == 0): <request.json> elif len(request.form)>0: <request.form>"```.